# setting wallpaper from assets

Tags: android, assets, wallpaper

when i try to set Wallpaper from Assets it takes time to get the job done so maybe there is easier way instead of my hardcode

```
public void Setwallpaper(int position , Context context) throws IOException{    
    AssetManager am = mContext.getAssets();
    nlist = am.list("Gallary");
     BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(am.open(nlist[position]));
     bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);

     buf.close();
    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
            .getInstance(context);
    try {
        myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Wallpaper set",
                0).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context,
                "Error setting wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

it takes about 3 secs to do it while i have seen other applications were able to do it in less than a sec any suggestion i will appreciate it  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
   WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager =WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    InputStream ims = getAssets().open("yourimage.jpg");
    myWallpapaerManager.setStream(ims)
```

Comment: i tried your method and its working so much faster but i have question how i can get image name "yourimage.jpg" from position in direct way instead of using this code `nlist = am.list("Gallary"); InputStream ims = mContext.getAssets().open(nlist[position]); `

Answer (score 0):

Above example works, don't forget to add permission