# Android - Setting wallpaper from file path takes longer than expected

Tags: android, android-wallpaper

I'm trying to set wallpaper from file path. However it takes more than 10 seconds and causes my app to freeze.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
public void SET_WALLPAPER_FROM_FILE_PATH (String file_path)
{
    Bitmap image_bitmap;
    File   image_file;
    FileInputStream fis;

    try {
        WallpaperManager wallpaper_manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(m_context);
        image_file                         = new File(file_path);
        fis                                = new FileInputStream(image_file);
        image_bitmap                       = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

        wallpaper_manager.setBitmap(image_bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have tried to use:

`wallpaper_manager.setStream(fis)`

instead of:

`wallpaper_manager.setBitmap(image_bitmap);`

as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15437477/4994743) but couldn't load the wallpaper.

Can anyone guide me?

Thanks

Comment: First of all you must decode image in background thread. And may be you need decode image with some options like inSampleSize

Comment: Is there class or documentation for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use AsyncTask,
in doInBackground method write something like this

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f,int WIDTH,int HIGHT){
    try {
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;
        final int REQUIRED_HIGHT=HIGHT;
        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale=1;
        while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
            scale*=2;

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I have started it in a thread, used the function, everything seems perfect but still it takes 4-5 seconds to load the wallpaper. Is there an actual solution for it?

Comment: Yes, it's ok. Decode big image is difficult operation.  So it depends on the size - the smaller size required the faster will be performed